# .htaccess redirection not working in ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, prestashop-1.7

To remove multiple slashes I wrote this condition that is working in windows system but not in Ubuntu 18.04 I don't know why..?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

I am getting this error in ubuntu system..

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access this resource.

And my URL changed this

```
http://in.decashop.localhost/p/8489882_500-boys-gym-short-sleeved-t-shirt-grey.html
```

to this

```
http://in.decashop.localhost/var/www/html/decashopglobal/www/in.decashop.localhost/p/8489882_500-boys-gym-short-sleeved-t-shirt-grey.html
```

if I put multiple slashes like

```
http://in.decashop.localhost///p/8489882_500-boys-gym-short-sleeved-t-shirt-grey.html
```

Answer (score 0):

**At** first, you can check apache's log. try to access your website using URL or IP and check your Webserver's ***log*** information.

**In ubuntu you can try:**

> sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

In most cases ***wrong permission*** is the main cause of this problem.

Comment: I checked in this file I have.. ```[Wed Feb 05 15:12:29.439189 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 20916] [client ::1:55108] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/decashop-countries/www/var/www
```

Comment: check your webserver configuration. usually config file is located in /etc/apache2/apache2. conf

Comment: in that file I have given.. 
```<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>```


```<Directory /usr/share>
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>```

```<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>```

AccessFileName .htaccess

```<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
 Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
> RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The output you are seeing is consistent with the directives you have posted, as you are missing the *scheme* (ie. `http`) on the *substitution* string in the `RewriteRule` directive (which presumably should be an *absolute* URL) - so I don't see how this would have "worked" on the Windows server? Unless you had a very different config (but even then it couldn't have worked the same way).

With the `RewriteRule` directive as written, the *substitution* string (ie. `%{HTTP_HOST}/%1`) would be seen as a *relative* URL and Apache would then add back the directory-prefix ie. `/var/www/html/decashopglobal/www/` prior to issueing the redirect - which naturally results in the malformed redirect you are seeing. If you had set a `RewriteBase` directive elsewhere in the config file, then this would have overridden this behaviour (although still wouldn't have produced the output you seem to be expecting).

Also note that these directives are intended to remove multiple slashes from the *start* of the URL-path only, not elsewhere in the URL-path.

So, you would need to change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

OR, remove the `HTTP_HOST` server variable altogether (to make the *substitution* string root-relative):

```
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as the erroneosu 301 (permanent) redirects will be cached persistently by the browser. (Test with 302s to avoid caching issues in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

This Rule worked for me..

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)/+(/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Thanks To All.